# How to get data from insterting data pdo mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

good morning 
i inserted data to my mysql database with pdo and i want get this data. Data go to database, but i dont know how to access to them

PHP code:

```
$saveMovie = $db->connect()
                    ->prepare("INSERT INTO test (nick,pass) VALUES
                        (:nick, :pass)");
                $saveMovie->execute(array(
                    "nick" => $nick,
                    "pass" => $pass,
                ));
```

and i want get this inserted data:

```
print_r($saveMovie->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));e
```

and i get the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: well `INSERT` is the command to **insert** data. did you really expect it to return what you just told it to store? that is what the `SELECT` statement is for.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you **cannot** get data right from insert.

Usually it makes no sense to do it, as you apparently have this data already, save for the auto generated fields. If it's just auto incremented id, you can get it the usual way:

```
$pdo = $db->connect();
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (nick,pass) VALUES (:nick, :pass)";
$row = array("nick" => $nick, "pass" => $pass);
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($row);
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$row['id'] = $id;
// now you have your inserted data with id
var_dump($row);
```

if you still want to select the very row that is in the database, then use that $id with a regular SELECT query.